# disable the button if the input is empty

Tags: angular, angular5

How can I disable the button if the input is empty, and enable it when the user start typing in the input, i tried that:

```
<input #new_field type="text" autocomplete="off" />
<p-button (onClick)="saveNewField(new_field.value)" [disabled]="new_field.value ==''" label="Save"></p-button>
```

and also this:

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" size="30" autocomplete="off" />
    <p-button (onClick)="saveNewField(searchText)" [disabled]="!searchText" label="Save"></p-button>
```

Answer (score 16):

Use ngModel and bind a value and use to disable button. Try this:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="searchText"/>

<p-button (onClick)="saveNewField(searchText)" [disabled]="!searchText" label="Save"></p-button>
```

Typescript file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  searchText: string;

  saveNewField(searchText) {
    console.log("searched Text", searchText);
  }
}
```

Comment: not working- the button start `disabled` and stay like this

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar when loading the page - the button is disabled, when start typing the the input the button stays disabled

Comment: added it to the post "and also this:"

Comment: also `(onClick)="saveNewField(searchText)"` , `searchText` is undefined

Comment: @AmitChigadani - Why wouldn't it work for an empty string?

Comment: @E.Meir - Did you declare `searchText: string` in code?

Comment: @ConnorsFan My mistake, I was in an impression that `searchText.length` was checked.

Comment: @ConnorsFan no, i didnt declare it in ts file, i tried to declare it- but its the same

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar , this solution is not working.. did you try it?

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar  yes i see, the disabled button is working, but why the value dont pass to `saveNewField` function

Comment: it's ok, `(onClick)` needs to be changed to `click`

Comment: its not working in my project cause i am using `Reactive form` in this page- so both input and button arer in that form, i am getting this error oin Chrome consolle- `ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive` what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **ngModel** for two way binding.There is no need to call the form.Simply call below.

```
<input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="some"/>
<button [disabled]="!some" >submit</button>
```

Also declare the variable some in component to bind the value.
ex:  some:any;

Comment: i cant do that (those elements - input + button) are part of Reactive Form, and i am getting an error for that in console `ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive`, if i am using `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` on the input element- it's working partially cause this button suppose to insert new field to `formArray` and its corrupting the array on this insert :/

Answer (score 2):

HTML part

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="doSomething()" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Click me</button>
```

TS part:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this._buildForm();
    }

private _buildForm() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            someComponent1: [],
            someComponent2: [, [Validators.required]]
        });
    }
```

### EXPLANATION

You should add validation for your components and set check `is form validated`. In my example above if Component 2 input field is empty your form will be invalidated and button disabled.

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Fill all input then button will be enabled

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="title" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pitch" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="text" />

<button type="button" class="btn save-btn" [disabled]="!title || !pitch || !text">Save</button>
```

you have form tag then try this

```
<form #experienceForm="ngForm">

    <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="date1" name="date1" required>

    <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="date2" name="date2" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn success-btn" [disabled]="!experienceForm.form.valid">Save</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form role="form" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <input class="form-input" type="number" [(ngModel)]="new_field" name="new_field" max="10">
    <p-button type="submit" (onClick)="saveNewField(new_field.value)" [disabled]="f.form.invalid">Test</p-button>
</form>
```

Comment: you should add an explanation so OP understands where they went wrong, avoids a generation of copy/paste devs :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the same issue for a while. Finally find something that worked for me. Try this:

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
   <input formControlName="searchText" type="text" size= "30" autocomplete="off" id="searchText" required/>
   <p-button (onclick)="saveNewField(searchText)" [disabled]="!searchText.value" label="Save"></p-button>
</form>
```

TS

```
export class searchFieldComponent implements OnInit {

    private searchText = string;
    searchText = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

    constructor(private serviceSearchField: SearchFieldService fb: FormBuilder) {
       this.myForm = fb.group({
          searchText: this.searchText
       });
    };
```

If this doesn't work, also create a model and call searchText in the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a template driven form approach, you can try this, the below code block is an example of registration form which take 4 inputs and contains a submit button:

```
<form #register="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitFn(register)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">First name: </label><br>
        <input #fname="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="f_name" placeholder="Enter firstname..." ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last_name">Last name: </label><br>
        <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="l_name" placeholder="Enter lastname..." ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email: </label><br>
        <input required type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="mail_id" placeholder="Enter email..." ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password: </label><br>
        <input required type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password..." ngModel>
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!register.form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The main thing you need is a template variable, in my case it is `#register="ngForm"`, and you will use it for validating the form at the submit button, by setting its value to disabled attribute like `[disabled]="!register.form.valid"` ->
Here, the submit btn will be disabled if the expression evaluates to `true`, the expression checks that if the form is valid or not, if it is valid then btn will be enabled & vice-versa.

Hope, it helps !
Don't forget to upvote if found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I did a trivial error while trying to achieve this functionality.

Just check the following add-ons:

1. Make sure you have FormModules imported in your parent module

   `imports: [FormsModule]`
2. If you want to do this within a form, you'd need to add `name` attribute.

`<form><input name="something" [(ngModel)]="something"></form>`

Ref: [NgModel Archive](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html#:%7E:text=When%20using%20the%20ngModel%20within,sync%20the%20value%20for%20you.)

---

Peace.